# APIs developed in Laravel framework, hosted in Apache server, is not getting any response when it is requested from Android and iOS mobile apps

Tags: php, android, apache, ssl, laravel-5

I've developed an api in Laravel 5.0 framework (PHP 5.6/MySql), and hosted in Apache 2.4.7 (Ubuntu), with SSL certificate given by GoDaddy as CA. All APIs were able to access since it was in http://. But after adding SSL certificate, none of the mobile applications (Android & iOS) can access those APIs, as it is giving an empty response.

But in postman and browsers, I'm getting the response like a charm. Response is in Json. Parsing library used by mobile developers is Async. Is there any step which we have to do either in client side or server side before moving into https://?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Apache domain configuration file. We should specify the paths to the

> SSLCertificateFile
>
> SSLCertificateKeyFile
>
> SSLCertificateChainFile

in the Apache domain configuration (which can be found in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/). But I missed the `SSLCertificateChainFile` parameter when I set up the SSL certificate for the domain. That was the problem.

The problems related to the SSL can be checked to an extent with the help of [SSLChecker](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html). Thanks to them and thanks to you all guys for the efforts.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, your code is probably throwing the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxx. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://yyy' is
therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

You need to update your API to allow requests from any origin. The [Laravel CORS library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) can help if this is the case.

Comment: Then how it worked in Postman and using PHP curl, etc...? I dont' think that is the problem. Temporarily the issue is solved by allowing all certificate by our android developer.

Comment: Because cURL and other tools may not always run into cross-domain issues. In any case, glad you got the issue resolved.